# C++ TopDown Pyramid

Tags: c++

I had an idea to make a program that would take user input and make a... I am not quite sure how to call it correctly, so my WIP is top down pyramid. So that we don't get confused it should look something like this.

If c is 5:

```
11111
10001
10101
10001
11111
```

If c is 7:

```
0000000
0111110
0100010
0101010
0100010
0111110
0000000
```

[Here is an image to help visualize the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WASKk.png)

The only conditions are that there has to be a 1 in the middle and that cin is odd.

Now, I've been thinking about it in my spare time and it seemed quite easy in my head, but when I try to put my thoughts into my code it never works out.
Is there anyone who could help me? I am quite desperate .-.

PS: Here is my WIP code so far (Please excuse my Czech ints and texts)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void FillArray(int **PyramidArray,int a,int b,int c);
void ExtractArray(int **PyramidArray,int a,int b,int c);
int main()
{
cout << "input array size.(only odd numbers)" << endl;
int c;
cin >> c;
if (c%2 == 0)
{
cout << "Only odd numbers!" << endl;
return 1;
}
int **PyramidArray;
    PyramidArray = new int*[c];
    for (int i =0;i<c;i++)
    {
        PyramidArray[i] = new int[i];
    }
    FillArray(PyramidArray,c,c,c);
    ExtractArray(PyramidArray,c,c,c);



return 0;
}

void FillArray(int **PyramidArray, int a, int b, int c)
{

    for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    {

        for (int j=0;j<b;j++)
        {
            PyramidArray [i][j] = 1;
        }
    }

 }
void ExtractArray(int **PyramidArray, int a,int b,int c)
 {
for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
    for (int j=0;j<b;j++)
        {
        cout << PyramidArray [i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to. I can translate those names if it helps tho.

Comment: Alrighty, it should be more comprehensible now. Thanks for your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For solving this kind of problem, if you find you need a `new`, then something is wrong. Just keep tracing the current state of printing, everything can be done in one-pass.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n = 0, half_n = 0;

    std::cin >> n;
    if ( n % 2 == 0 ) return -1;
    half_n = n / 2;

    // the first symbol to print, 1 or 0
    int start_symbol = 1 - half_n % 2;

    // how many steps from beginning require alternating symbol ?
    int alternate_range = 0;

    // 0 for upperhalf, 1 for lowerhalf
    int direct = 0; 

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
        int current_symbol = start_symbol;
        for ( int j = 0; j < alternate_range; ++j ) {
            std::cout << current_symbol;
            current_symbol = 1 - current_symbol;
        }

        for ( int j = alternate_range; j < n - alternate_range; ++j ) {
            std::cout << current_symbol;
        }

        for ( int j = n - alternate_range; j < n; ++j ) {
            current_symbol = 1 - current_symbol;
            std::cout << current_symbol;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";

        if ( alternate_range == half_n ) {
            direct = 1;
        }

        if ( direct == 0 ) {
            ++alternate_range;
        } else {
            --alternate_range;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you,
I managed to get my own solution to this problem about 10 minutes ago, but I appreciate that you took your time to answer my question :)